# Using array.map() to find elements from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects and I'd like to return an array of all the `id`s. For example:

```
const arr = [
    {Locations:[{id:2129, Name: 'testAA'}, {id:3431, Name: 'testAB'}, {id:4373, Name: 'testAC'}]},
    {Locations:[{id:2545, Name: 'testBA'}, {id:3431, Name: 'testBB'}]}
];
```

I'd like to return: `[2129, 3431, 4373, 2545, 3431]`

I've tried to following:

```
arr.map((value) => {
    let newarray = [];
    return newarray += value['Locations'].map(ID => ID.id);
});
```

This returns: `["2129,3431,4373", "2545,3431"]`

How do I combine those two arrays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that your input and output aren't a 1-to-1 mapping, this doesn't seem like a great use-case for `.map()`. Instead, I'd consider using `.map()` only on the inner array, but using `.reduce()` on the outer.

```js
const arr = [{Locations:[{id:2129, Name: 'testAA'}, {id:3431, Name: 'testAB'}, {id:4373, Name: 'testAC'}]},{Locations:[{id:2545, Name: 'testBA'}, {id:3431, Name: 'testBB'}]}];     

const result = arr.reduce((acc,{Locations}) => [...acc, ...Locations.map(i=>i.id)], []);

console.log(result);
```

As an alternative, you could use `.concat()`:

```js
const arr = [{Locations:[{id:2129, Name: 'testAA'}, {id:3431, Name: 'testAB'}, {id:4373, Name: 'testAC'}]},{Locations:[{id:2545, Name: 'testBA'}, {id:3431, Name: 'testBB'}]}];     

const result = arr.reduce((acc,{Locations}) => acc.concat(Locations.map(i=>i.id)), []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: When the accumulator and subarray get flattened but you're producing an output array, `flatMap` is the right tool (but this is good if browser compatibility prohibit, although if this was the case `[].concat()` is a good `flatMap` alternative). This looks like quadratic time due to `...acc`.

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks. I've included an alternative.

Comment: `concat` does the same thing--makes a totally new array on each iteration, unfortunately. If you have to use `reduce`, it's important to `return a;` so that the result array isn't rebuilt `arr.length` times. But then it gets very ugly-looking which shows that `reduce(...., [])` is an antipattern (should be `map`). Prefer [Mamum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59331188/6243352) or [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59331231/6243352) if compatibility is needed. Feel free to benchmark them.

Comment: @ggorlen I don't disagree, just doesn't make much sense to alter my answer to mimic alternatives that were already provided :)

Comment: Absolutely, and it's not a bad answer by any means! Generally most of the data is going to be small, so I don't mean to be overly pedantic.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with [**Array.prototype.flatMap()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

> The `flatMap()` method first maps each element using a mapping function, then flattens the result into a new array. It is identical to a map() followed by a flat() of depth 1, but `flatMap()` is often quite useful, as merging both into one method is slightly more efficient.

and [**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map)

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```js
const arr = [
    {Locations:[{id:2129, Name: 'testAA'}, {id:3431, Name: 'testAB'}, {id:4373, Name: 'testAC'}]},
    {Locations:[{id:2545, Name: 'testBA'}, {id:3431, Name: 'testBB'}]}
];
const newarray = arr.flatMap(i => i.Locations.map(j => j.id));
console.log(newarray);
```

Comment: Just a note- Not very cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```js
arr.map((value) => {
    let newarray = [];
    return newarray += value['Locations'].map(ID => ID.id);
}).join(',').split(',').map((value) => parseInt(value, 10));
```

Here's the "chain of events":
`["2129,3431,4373", "2545,3431"]` -> `"2129,3431,4373,2545,3431"` -> `["2129","3431","4373","2545","3431"]` -> `[2129, 3431, 4373, 2545, 3431]`

Comment: Now that I look at it, Tyler's answer above is much cleaner and better- use that one instead.

Answer (score 0):

I like Tyler Roppers answer

concat the two arrays https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

haven't tested by maybe `return newarray.concat(value['Locations'].map(ID => ID.id));`

Could also run something like this which might be a bit cleaner.

```
arr.map((value) => {
    let newArray = [];
    Locations.map((location) => {
        return newArray.push(location.id)
    });
    if(newArray.length) return newArray;
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have two arrays there, you have an array of two concatenated strings. You don't need the `newarray[]` at all; `.map()` returns a new array for you.

When you get that you can combine it with a `reduce()`.

What you want will look like this:

```
arr
    .map((value) => value['Locations']
        .map(ID => ID.id))
    .reduce((accum, arr)=>accum.concat(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) is the correct tool for this scenario, but if browser compatibility prohibits its use, you can flatten using [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const arr = [{Locations:[{id:2129, Name: 'testAA'}, {id:3431, Name: 'testAB'}, {id:4373, Name: 'testAC'}]}, {Locations:[{id:2545, Name: 'testBA'}, {id:3431, Name: 'testBB'}]}];

console.log([].concat(...arr.map(e => e.Locations.map(e => e.id))));
```